# PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc Gotchas?

Tags: python

All the documentation for `PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc()` smells of gotchas ("naive misuse"), but nothing goes into specific things to be careful of. Can anyone enlighten me on the details?

All I've found so far is that [C extensions can swallow exceptions](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2006-May/064984.html), including the one you're trying to throw.

Answer (score 0):

`.read()` will swallow most exceptions.